# Alert getting scheduled an hour late when hosted on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, hangfire

I'm using hangfire to schedule sending an email alert at a time specified by the user. when I test the app on localhost the alert is scheduled for the correct time, when i send a request to the live app hosted on Azure the request is scheduled for an hour later than it should be.

I assume the problem is my lack of knowledge on DateTimeOffset. What I am doing in my JobScheduler class is

```
    public class JobScheduler : IJobScheduler
    {
        private EmailManager _emailManager;

        public JobScheduler(IAlertManager alertManager)
        {
            _alertManager = alertManager;
        }
        public string ScheduleRaiseDateAlert( DateDetail date)
        {
            DateTimeOffset jobRunTime = ConvertToDateTimeOffSet(date.CheckInTime);
            return BackgroundJob.Schedule(()=> _alertManager.RaiseAlertAsync(date.Id, true), jobRunTime.DateTime);
        }
        private DateTimeOffset ConvertToDateTimeOffSet(DateTime futureDateTime)
        {
            futureDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(futureDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            DateTimeOffset ScheduleTime = futureDateTime;
            return ScheduleTime;
        }
    }
```

***date.CheckInTime*** is the datetime the user should be sent an email

for example: if ***date.CheckInTime = 17/04/2018 19:02:00*** when i send the request on local host the job will be scheduled for that date and time, when i send the same request to the app hosted on azure the time the job is scheduled for is ***17/04/2018 20:02:00***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the `DateTimeOffset.DateTime` would be treated as a local date time, you could check the `Kind` property of your `jobRunTime.DateTime` instance sent to `BackgroundJob.Schedule`.

For the method overloading for `BackgroundJob.Schedule` which supports the `DateTimeOffset` parameter, the stored **EnqueueAt** would be `DateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime` of your `DateTimeOffset` parameter.

For the `TimeSpan` parameter, the stored **EnqueueAt** would be the current UTC date time adding your specified TimeSpan.

Moreover, if you pass the local time `DateTime` instance to `BackgroundJob.Schedule`, the stored **EnqueueAt** would be converted to the relevant UTC date time.

Since you did not provide how did you construct the `DateDetail`, I would recommend you to check the stored tasks to narrow down this issue. I used UseSqlServerStorage, for this approach, you could check the state of scheduled task under `HangFire.State` table.

```
{"EnqueueAt":"2018-04-20T06:39:28.0305044Z","ScheduledAt":"2018-04-18T06:39:29.5398973Z"}
```

The `ScheduledAt` stands for the UTC date time you created this task, the `EnqueueAt` stands for the UTC date time when the task would be triggered.

Comment: Appreciate the answered helped a lot, just want to clarify _"For the TimeSpan parameter, the stored EnqueueAt would be the current UTC date time adding your specified TimeSpan."_  are you saying it will convert the time in my TimeSpan to UTC and store it

Comment: The `EnqueueAt` would be `DateTime.UtcNow.Add(<your-specified-timespan-parameter>)`, and you could create the demo project to check it and have a better understanding of it.